# Need help on creating triangle mesh from height map (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, mesh, javafx-3d, heightmap

I have a program that generates a height map (2D array of integers from 0-255) and builds a 3D view using a Shape3D "Box" object for each 'pixel' with a height proportional to its value in the height map. This creates a boxy-looking terrain that looks cool. My program also creates a corresponding "Color map" to map what color each box in the terrain should be.

I want to be able to also turn this height map into a mesh that can be textured using the color map.

2D Height and color map
[image: 2D Height and color map]

Colored triangle mesh created from height map and color map
[image: Desired mesh with colorsp]

(These are images I grabbed off google)

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I get it right, you want to build a `HeightMapMesh`, based on a grid of 2D points `{x, y}`, with a given height or `z` value for each point. This value would be directly related to the pixel's color at the same location of a given 2D image.

Getting the vertices is relatively easy: you create the 2D grid, and you get the color using a PixelReader.

Building the mesh is not that easy, but you could just build a regular mesh based on the rectangular 2D image.

There is also another option: given a number of vertices, you could generate a mesh with a Delaunay triangulation.

This is already implemented in the [FXyz](https://github.com/FXyz) library: [Surface3DMesh](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/master/FXyz-Core/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/shapes/primitives/Surface3DMesh.java).

To use it, just add the dependency to your project:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.fxyz3d:fxyz3d:0.5.0"
}
```

The following application will do a rough approximation at the HeighMapMesh you are looking for.

It uses the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqK3y.png) you have posted to create `List<Point3D> data` based on a PixelReader every 5 pixels on x and y, with just a small sample of the colors of that image.

With this list, two surfaces are created, one will be filled and rendered with a texture map based on the height of each vertex, using the same color list. The other one will be used as a wireframe to be rendered on top.

```
public class HeighMapMeshTest extends Application {

    private static final int PIXEL_SIZE = 5;

    private static final List<Color> COLOR_LIST = Arrays.asList(Color.web("#3b6eca"),
            Color.web("#d7d588"), Color.web("#60a318"), Color.web("#457517"), Color.web("#467610"),
            Color.web("#654f44"), Color.web("#56453d"), Color.web("#fdfefc"), Color.web("#ffffff"));

    private final Rotate rotateX = new Rotate(-10, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    private final Rotate rotateY = new Rotate(5, Rotate.Y_AXIS);

    private double mousePosX;
    private double mousePosY;
    private double mouseOldX;
    private double mouseOldY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group sceneRoot = new Group();

        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
        camera.setNearClip(0.1);
        camera.setFarClip(10000.0);
        camera.getTransforms().addAll (rotateX, rotateY, new Translate(0, 0, -800));

        Scene scene = new Scene(sceneRoot, 1000, 600, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        scene.setCamera(camera);

        List<Point3D> data = processImage();

        Surface3DMesh heightMapMesh = new Surface3DMesh(data);
        heightMapMesh.setDrawMode(DrawMode.FILL);
        heightMapMesh.setTextureModeVertices3D(new Palette.ListColorPalette(COLOR_LIST), p -> -p.y);

        Surface3DMesh wireframe = new Surface3DMesh(data);
        wireframe.setTextureModeNone(Color.BLACK);

        Group mapGroup = new Group(heightMapMesh, wireframe);
        mapGroup.getTransforms().add(new Translate(-500, 100, 0));
        sceneRoot.getChildren().addAll(mapGroup, new AmbientLight());

        scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            mousePosX = event.getSceneX();
            mousePosY = event.getSceneY();
        });

        scene.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            mousePosX = event.getSceneX();
            mousePosY = event.getSceneY();
            rotateX.setAngle(rotateX.getAngle() - (mousePosY - mouseOldY));
            rotateY.setAngle(rotateY.getAngle() + (mousePosX - mouseOldX));
            mouseOldX = mousePosX;
            mouseOldY = mousePosY;
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("F(X)yz - HeightMapMesh");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private List<Point3D> processImage() {
        Image image = new Image(VoxelTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/8rF9BXu.png"));
        PixelReader pixelReader = image.getPixelReader();
        int width = (int) image.getWidth();
        int height = (int) image.getHeight();

        List<Point3D> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int y = 0; y < height - PIXEL_SIZE / 2; y += PIXEL_SIZE){
            for (int x = 0; x < width - PIXEL_SIZE / 2; x += PIXEL_SIZE){
                Color color = pixelReader.getColor(x + PIXEL_SIZE / 2, y + PIXEL_SIZE / 2);
                float h = Math.max(COLOR_LIST.indexOf(color) * 10, 0);
                data.add(new Point3D((float) x, -h, (float) (height - y)));
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

As a result:

[image: MapHeightMesh]

Of course, this can be improved in many different ways.

**EDIT**

Once the 3D mesh has been created, it can be exported to an .OBJ file, including the texture applied.

FXyz already includes [`OBJWriter`](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/master/FXyz-Core/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/io/OBJWriter.java) for this purpose.

This code:

```
OBJWriter writer = new OBJWriter((TriangleMesh) heightMapMesh.getMesh(), "mapHeight");
writer.setTextureColors(9);
writer.exportMesh();
```

will generate `mapHeight.obj` and `mapHeight.mtl`, where a diffuse image named `palette_9.png` is used.

However, this palette image doesn't use the custom palette we have defined.

In order to export the custom colorPalette, we need to create a `Palette`, and save it to disk:

```
OBJWriter writer = new OBJWriter((TriangleMesh) heightMapMesh.getMesh(), "mapHeight");
writer.setTextureColors(9);
Palette.ListColorPalette colorPalette = 
        new Palette.ListColorPalette(COLOR_LIST);
Palette palette = new Palette(9, colorPalette);
palette.createPalette(true);
writer.exportMesh();
```

Verify that the palette file is a 3x3 image with the colors from `COLOR_LIST`.

Now you can open the obj file with [3DViewer](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/tree/develop/apps/samples/3DViewer) to check that it was exported correctly.

[image: 3DViewer]

Comment: How would I use FXyz to export this mesh as an obj file (with the textured colors)?

Comment: Check [ObjWriter](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/a580598f8a4d014225bb665f669c906cf28aa0e4/FXyz-Core/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/io/OBJWriter.java#L67)

Comment: I am able to export the Surface3DMesh as an obj with the mesh. How would I add the texture to this obj?